# Could not find stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005

I created a procedure to rebuild indexes with a cursor. Instead of executing properly, I get an error message:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62
>   
> Could not find stored procedure

What to do to get rid of this situation?

```
USE [ACT]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedure]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @idx_name VARCHAR(200) -- Index name  
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(256) -- Table Name
DECLARE @sql varchar(500) 

DECLARE Index_Rebuild_Cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ps.OBJECT_ID)tbl_name,b.name idx_name
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS ps
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS b ON ps.OBJECT_ID = b.OBJECT_ID
AND ps.index_id = b.index_id 
WHERE ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent>80

OPEN Index_Rebuild_Cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM Index_Rebuild_Cursor INTO @tableName,@idx_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

 SET @sql='ALTER INDEX '+@idx_name+' ON '+@tableName+' REBUILD'
 EXEC @sql

 FETCH NEXT FROM Index_Rebuild_Cursor INTO @tableName,@idx_name
END   

CLOSE Index_Rebuild_Cursor   
DEALLOCATE Index_Rebuild_Cursor

END
```

Comment: [ACT] is the correct database?

Comment: yes ACT is the correct one.

Comment: http://sqlserverlearner.com/2011/msg-2812-level-16-state-62-line-1-could-not-find-stored-procedure

Comment: yes bummi. EXEC (@sql) works.

Comment: Does your database have multiple schemas? Is the default schema to your login set to something else, other than "dbo"?

Comment: Instead of creating your own procedure to rebuild indexes, why not leverage an already-tested solution? I recommend [Ola Hallengren's scripts](http://ola.hallengren.com), and use them in our production environment with great success.

Answer (score 5):

`EXEC @sql` is invalid syntax (you need `EXEC(@sql);` - those parentheses are important). Nonetheless, I highly recommend:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'ALTER ...';
-----------^ this N is important too
...

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Doing this as a habit makes sure that you will be able to use strongly typed parameters when you can.

Answer (score 0):

search for the sp with

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.sql_modules
WHERE   definition LIKE '%SET @sql=''ALTER INDEX ''+@idx_name+'' ON ''+@tableName+'' REBUILD''%'
```

if it exists under a different name you might find it with this query.

Comment: There is no stored procedure to find - did you look at the OP's code? The error happens inside the procedure and is a result of the `EXEC` call - which does not call a stored procedure.